# why this file is not compiling?? As it shows errors

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,superscriptaddress,reprint,%,nofootinbib,tightenlines,nobibnotes
dvipsnames]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{youngtab}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[caption=false,,subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subfig}
 \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}
 \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
the following added by Hubert 21Jan.
\usepackage{soul}
\setstcolor{blue}
\newcommand\hdg[1]{\textcolor{red}{[#1]}}
\newcommand\aeysha[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\textsc{[#1]}}}

 \newcommand{\vcenterytableau}[2][]{%
  \begin{gathered}
 \tiny{\yng(1,1)}
   \end{gathered}
 }

\%\usepackage{soul}
%%%%%

\begin{document}
\title{Continuous variable entanglement distribution between arbitrary parties }


\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
\section{Gaussian states}
\label{sec:gaussian}

\section{Distribution of entanglement to three parties}
\subsection{The scheme}

\subsection{Applying the scheme} 

\section{Distribution of entanglement between arbitrary number of parties}
\label{sec:generaln}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The error is at `\%\usepackage{soul}`. Remove the `\%`.

Comment: ... and you can't have `the following added by Hubert 21Jan.` before `\begin{document}`,you need to load `xcolor`  earlier and you cannot have `subcaption` and `subfig` and so on. To be honest, this is a really unfortunate mix of packages. You use `revtex4-1`, I wouldn't, you load `physics`, I would never, and so on.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat can you please modify this code? thanks in advance

Comment: You load mutually incompatible packages. In order to fix the code, one would have to know what you really need. One has to drop some package(s) to get a working code.